# Read a file with Scanner Java doesn't work even with correct directory

Tags: java, eclipse, file

I am trying to read values from a file and process them. 
I have a code as below. Even the address of the file is correct, it can't find the file.

```
private Scanner x;

public void openFile()
{
    try{

        x = new Scanner(new File("D:\test.txt"));
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("no such a file found");
    }
}


public void readFile()
{
    while(x.hasNext())   // ERROR LINE
    { 
        String a = x.next();
        String b = x.next();
        String c = x.next();
System.out.printf("%s %s %s\n",a,b,c);      
    }

}

public void closeFile()
{
    x.close();
}

}
public class readTest {

public static void main(String[] args){
ReadFile r = new ReadFile();
r.openFile();
r.readFile(); //ERROR LINE
r.closeFile();
}
}
```

I got the

```
     no such a file found
     Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
     at ReadFile.readFile(ReadFile.java:23)
     at readTest.main(readTest.java:7)
```

exception. 
How should i do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\t` is an escape seqence. You have to escape that backslash again. Try `D:\\test.txt`.

> A character preceded by a backslash \ is an escape sequence and has
>   special meaning to the compiler.

```
\t  Insert a tab in the text at this point.
\b  Insert a backspace in the text at this point.
\n  Insert a newline in the text at this point.
\r  Insert a carriage return in the text at this point.
\f  Insert a formfeed in the text at this point.
\'  Insert a single quote character in the text at this point.
\"  Insert a double quote character in the text at this point.
\\  Insert a backslash character in the text at this point.
```

See [the Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html).

Comment: @user3864949 Remember you can accept an answer if it solves your question. It will show others that this question was already answered in a acceptable manner and save them a bit of their time :)